# PackageManager Excluding feature android.hardware.location.gps

Tags: android

I am trying to run GPS sample application on Android 4.4.2. I am getting the following error message in the logcat.

```
I/PackageManager( 2295): Excluding feature android.hardware.location.gps
```

Can any one tell me what is this problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: Do you request location permission in manifest?